# Drawing text on video with avconv only at the start of the video

Tags: video, libav

I want to embed the creation date of personnal videos, but only at their start (let say the 10 first seconds).

I'm using the [drawtext](http://libav.org/avconv.html#drawtext) of avconv:

> avconv -i input.avi  -vf
>   "drawtext=fontcolor=white:fontsize=30:fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-L.ttf:text='$date':x=30:y=h-text_h-30"
>   test.mpg

but I do not find any option to tell to just write the date on only a portion of the video. I could split the start of the video, or make an srt file, but there is probably an easier solution.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution could be to use the "Timeline editing" functionalities of ffmpeg (http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-Timeline-editing)

Add the following option in the option of the VF you use.

```
enable='between(t, 0, 10)'
```

so the filter should draw the text only during 10s and bypass frame after.

As you use avconv you could have a look at https://libav.org/avconv.html#toc-drawtext

the draw text filter seems to have :
a 'n' option to specify the number of frame where the text must be draw
and a 't' option to express a time stamp

So specify n='10*your vidéo framerate'

Comment: I have a feeling `avconv` does not have this capability (but I did not check).

Comment: Oups, yes I missed that its cmd line didn't use ffmpeg as the tag mentioned !